# Segmentation Fault within Assembly Program caused by Subprogram

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am currently continuing work upon a project for my Computer Architecture class in which a postfix expression is converted to a completely parenthesized infix expression. However, I am having difficulty locating how I am getting a segmentation fault when I run the program. I know that it is directly related to my subprogram, readPostfix, that calls upon the method append which calls upon the lengthIs method. How should I go about fixing this issue that I am facing?

I have tried omitting the use of push in order to save the values of the registers in order to try and fix the program, but I figure that through that I would be losing the values of ecx, which is needed for the loop, and some other important ones.

This is a section of the code that I would like to function correctly. If it runs correctly it should output A+B...

```
%include "asm_io.inc"

segment .data                           
    postfix     db  "AB+", 0 
    maxSize     equ 100     

segment .bss                                                    
    postLength  resb 1                              

segment .text
    global  _asm_main

_asm_main:
    enter   0,0                                     ; setup routine
    pusha

    push    postfix
    call    lengthIs
    add     esp,4
    mov     [postLength],eax
    call    print_int

    push    postLength
    push    postfix
    call    postfixToInfix
    add     esp, 8

    popa
    mov     eax, 0                              ; return back to C
    leave                     
    ret



; A subprogram that converts postfix expression to a fully parenthesized infix expression
segment .data

segment .bss
operator        resd 1

segment .text

postfixToInfix:                             
    push    ebp                                 
    mov     ebp, esp                            

    mov     edx, [ebp + 8]                      
    mov     ecx, [ebp + 12]                     
    mov     esi, 0                              

infixLoop:
    mov     al,[ebx + esi]
    inc     esi
    cmp     eax,'+'                         
    je      operation                       
    cmp     eax, ' '
    je      infix_exit

    push    eax
    inc     esi
    loop    infixLoop

operation:
    mov     [operator], al
    pop     ebx                                 
    pop     edx                                 

    push    eax                                                                 
    push    ecx                                 
    push    edx                                 
    push    esi                                 
    push    esp                                 

    push    operator
    push    ebx
    push    1
    call    append
    add     esp, 12

    push    ebx
    push    1
    call    append
    add     esp, 12

    pop     esp
    pop     esi
    pop     edx
    pop     ecx
    pop     eax

    push    ebx

infix_exit:
    inc     esi
    loop    infixLoop

    pop     eax
    call    print_string
    pop     ebp                                 
    ret                                         

; A subprogram that gets the length of the postfix expression

segment .text

lengthIs:                                   
    push    ebp                                 
    mov     ebp, esp                            

    mov     eax, 0                              
    mov     ebx, [ebp + 8]                      
    mov     esi, 0                              
    mov     ecx, maxSize                        

length_loop:                                    
    cmp     [ebx + esi], dword 0                
    je      length_exit                         
    inc     eax                                 
    inc     esi                                 
    loop    length_loop                         

length_exit:                                    
    pop ebp                                     
    ret                                         


; A subprogram strcat appends the contents of one string to the end of another
; strcat(str1,str2)
; Result: str1= str1 + str2
segment .bss
append_length resd 1
segment .text
append:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp

    mov     edx, [ebp + 16]                         

    push    edx
    call    lengthIs
    add     esp, 4
    mov     [append_length], eax
    mov     eax, 0

    mov     ebx, [ebp + 12]                     
    mov     edx, [ebp + 16]                         
    mov     ecx, [append_length] 
    mov     edi, 0
    mov     esi, [ebp + 8]                      

append_loop:
    mov     al, [edx + edi]
    mov     [ebx + esi], al
    add     esi, 1
    add     edi, 1
    loop    append_loop

    pop     ebp
    ret
```

Comment: This is not very minimal for a [mcve].  Use your debugger, and strip this down to a minimal example that still faults the same way as your full version.  If you don't spot the bug while doing that, edit your question to show *where* the segfault happens (which instruction), and what the register values are when it happens.

Comment: What calling convention are you trying to use?  Your `readPostfix` clobbers the caller's EBX and ESI.  That's fine, but if you're using custom calling conventions (not i386 System V), then normally you should document your functions with INPUTS: / OUTPUTS: / CLOBBERS: on 3 separate lines.  There's zero reason to use 2 registers there, BTW, you could just increment a pointer.  You're already using a separate loop counter with the slow `loop` instruction, not doing `cmp esi, maxSize` / `jb` or something. Anyway, if any of your other functions modify registers you're not expecting, it could crash

Comment: I’m gonna be completely honest, the current class I’m in does not have access to a debugger to find out where the segmentation fault occurs. We have to upload our programs to an external server and run them from there, and we simply aren’t able to easily debug them. Thank you for the other tips though too.

Comment: Well that's just ridiculous.  Writing asm without a debugger is like trying to build a robot blindfolded.  A debugger is even more essential for asm than most languages, because you can't just sprinkle debug-prints easily, and bugs are commonly crash bugs, not logic bugs that print wrong output.  And because the machine state is fixed size.  Anyway, install a dev env on your local machine (maybe inside a VM), and there are even some online dev envs with a debugger like https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_gcc_assembler.  (But that's for GAS syntax, not NASM.)

Comment: As far as Stack Overflow is concerned, the fact that you haven't already set up a debugger doesn't excuse not having a [mcve].  It's definitely expected that people debug their own code down to some small snippet that is puzzling them, not post their *whole* non-working program.  i.e. figure out which part isn't working, and reduce it to a program that calls that with constant inputs.  See https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I will try to set up a dev env when I get the chance, thank you. In the mean time I attempted to cut the code down in length to include the crucial part that still gives the same issue. The code should output A+B, from the constant input AB+, yet it gets the segmentation fault.

Comment: Are you sure your "external server" doesn't have GDB installed?  If it's a Linux machine, it probably will.  If you can run your program there, you probably have interactive shell access, not just file-upload.  It's inconvenient to re-upload all the time, but you could either automate that or use a local editor that can save over SSH (e.g. emacs I assume, or anything with SSHFS on a Linux desktop.)  Or you could edit on the server if it has a decent editor like vim or emacs that works over SSH.